# Evaluate and Store Complex Expression in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on an accounting VBA program that will post Journal entries to a Ledger, and then generate trial balances (i.e. print out the values on a new sheet following "Bal. " in the Ledger). To do this, I need a way to assign the numerical part of the balance cells to a variable or collection. Unfortunately, when I use Debug.Print I see the only value stored is 0 (I am testing just with Common Stock). My expression is: `y = Application.Evaluate("=SUM(R[-" & x & "]C:R[-1]C)-SUM(R[-" & x & "]C[1]:R[-1]C[1])")` where `y` represents the balance of Common Stock. How do I properly store the balance value in a variable?

[image: Screen Recording]

```
' TODO BE ABLE TO RUN MULTIPLE TIMES
' CHECK FOR POSTED MARK & START WRITING WHEN
' r = "one of the keys", or just creates new Ledger Worksheet every time

Sub MacCompileData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim data, Key
Dim r As Range
Dim cLedger As Collection, cList As Collection
Set cLedger = New Collection

With Worksheets("Journal")
    lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastRow
        Key = Trim(.Cells(x, 2))
        On Error Resume Next
        Set cList = cLedger(Key)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set cList = New Collection
            cLedger.Add cList, Key
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        cLedger(Key).Add Array(.Cells(x, 1).Value, .Cells(x, 3).Value, .Cells(x, 4).Value)
        Worksheets("Journal").Cells(x, 5).Value = ChrW(&H2713)

    Next
End With

With Worksheets("Ledger")

    Dim IsLiability As Boolean
    Dim y As Integer

    For Each r In .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        If r <> "" Then

        On Error Resume Next
        Key = Trim(r.Text)

        If Key = "LIABILITIES" Then
            IsLiability = True
        End If

        data = getLedgerArray(cLedger(Key))

        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Set list = cLedger(Key)
            x = cLedger(Key).Count
            With r.Offset(2).Resize(x, 3)
                .Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=r.Offset(1)
                .Offset(-x).Value = data

                If IsLiability Then
                    .Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=""Bal. "" & TEXT(SUM(R[-" & x & "]C:R[-1]C)-SUM(R[-" & x & "]C[1]:R[-1]C[1]),""$#,###"")"

                    ' LOOK HERE FOR Y
                    y = Application.Evaluate("=SUM(R[-" & x & "]C:R[-1]C)-SUM(R[-" & x & "]C[1]:R[-1]C[1])")

                    Debug.Print "Common Stock Balance Equals "; y

                Else
                    .Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=""Bal. "" & TEXT(SUM(R[-" & x & "]C:R[-1]C)-SUM(R[-" & x & "]C[1]:R[-1]C[1]),""$#,###"")"
                End If


                r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
            End With
        End If

        On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next

End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function getLedgerArray(c As Collection)
Dim data
Dim x As Long
ReDim data(1 To c.Count, 1 To 3)

For x = 1 To c.Count
    data(x, 1) = c(x)(0)
    data(x, 2) = c(x)(1)
    data(x, 3) = c(x)(2)
Next
getLedgerArray = data
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that I was able to figure out, though I am not sure if it is the most efficient. In line before the formula is set, I set a `Range` named `BalanceCell` to the cell where the formula will be written. I then used the `Mid` Function to get the string number value from the cell (since the length of "Bal. " is always 5 characters) after the formula is put into `BalanceCell`.

```
If IsLiability Then
                    Set BalanceCell = .Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 1)
                    BalanceCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""Bal. "" & TEXT(SUM(R[-" & x & "]C:R[-1]C)-SUM(R[-" & x & "]C[1]:R[-1]C[1]),""$#,###"")"

                    y = Mid(BalanceCell.Value, 6, Len(BalanceCell.Value))

                    Debug.Print "Common Stock Balance is "; y
```

[image: ScreenRecording]